# Review list for top users doesn't update

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I noticed this yesterday and am noticing it again today. After a few hours of waiting, it doesn't seem like the **Top Reviewers** are updating. I show that today I have more reviews than the last user in the list, yet I am not in the list. This is the review list for **Suggested Edits** on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an old bug with the way top users were shown in the top reviewers list.  This has been fixed awhile ago but please let us know if you have further issues.

Comment: "let us know if you have further issues". Ok - having them now. I've been monitoring the [google-apps-script] top users for a couple of days, and haven't seen it change. Yeah, I'm shooting for number 1, thanks for asking!